# Unable to reduce the step size without violating minimum step size

Tags: matlab, size, warnings, simulink, step

When running the model using the SIM function ex: sim('model', value), it works normally when setting small values of ten or less ex: sim('model', 10), but at large values ex: sim('model', 100) the simulations do not end at all, as the following warning appears:

Warning: Unable to reduce the step size without violating minimum step size of 4.2354948260225361E-14 for 1
consecutive times at time 11.921858075128016.  Continuing simulation with the step size restricted to
4.2354948260225361E-14 and using an effective relative error tolerance of 0.0015353291047024145, which is greater
than the specified relative error tolerance of 0.001. This usually may be caused by the high stiffness of the system.
Please check the model 'Model' or increase Number of
consecutive min steps</ sldiag >

Comment: what is the question? The error message suggests a way to solve it

Comment: Ander Biguri
 There are no errors, but the simulation does not stop completely, with the appearance of the warning, as I mentioned above

Comment: That is still not a question!